# What kind of function satisfy those conditions?

Tags: functions

I need a function to compute score of object, and the function should satisfy following conditions:

1. takes two variable x and y, output z;
2. small x, small y output z1;
3. small x, big y output z2;
4. big x, small y output z3;
5. big x, big y output z4;
6. z1 > z2 > z3 > z4;

I have try function like: z = ax + by + c, but I can't make it work.

Comment: **Welcome** to the site ! To show what you want, why don't you post a real table of data points $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ ?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Do you mean $z_1 > z_2 > z_3 > z_4$? (You repeated $z_3$). And have you tried negative values for $a$ and $b$ (e.g. $a=-1$ and $b=-2$)? By the way, you can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) to make equations look better.

Answer (score 1):

Map small and big $x$ and $y$ values to $x'$ and $y'$ as follows:

$x \text{ small } \Rightarrow x'=0\\
x \text{ big } \Rightarrow x'=2\\
y \text{ small } \Rightarrow y'=0\\
y \text{ big } \Rightarrow y'=1$

then set $z=x'+y'$. You have $z_1=0, z_2=1, z_3=2, z_4=3$ and $z_1<z_2<z_3<z_4$.